# How to combine a relative top with an absolute bottom in CSS?

Tags: css

I need to define a `div` which must stay with the top at the normal position, which differs from the top of the surrounding element:

```
position:relative
top:0
```

and which grows in the height up to the size of the surrounding element:

```
position:absolute
bottom:0
```

I have no idea how to combine the both. Whenever I use a relative box I loose the absolute bottom and whenever I use an absolute box I loose the relative top.

Can anybody help me how to do this in CSS?

Here is an example:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <style type="text/css">
  @media screen {
      body {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
      }
      #head {
          background-color: gray;
      }
      #rel {
          background-color: green;
          position: relative;
          top: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          float: left;
      }
      #abs {
          background-color: red;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          float: left;
      }
  }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div id="head">
      <h1>Head</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="abs">
      <h2>absolute</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="rel">
      <h2>relative</h2>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

"relative" does not grow at all and "absolute" grows too much.

Comment: Why can't you do `height: 100%`?

Comment: @Blender: because the div is not at the top of the surrounding element and does not have the height of the surrounding element. It has a relative vertical position I need to take care of.

Answer (score 2):

```
div {
    top:0;
    height:100%; /* height calculated based off the height of parent element */
    margin:0;
}
```

[height property CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/height)

Comment: This does not work, because the child does not have the same height but only the same bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Use display:table on the outer div and display table-row on the inner ones:
See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JKQ2y/15/
Html:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="rel">
    <div class="m b">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="m r"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.outer{
  border:1px solid black;
  height:100px; width: 100px
  display:table;
}
.rel {
  height:30px;
  display:table-row;
}
.inner {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position:relative;
  display:table-cell;
}
.m {height:100%;}
.m.b {border:1px solid blue;}
.m.r {border:1px solid red;}
```

Comment: Sorry but your answer does not match my question. Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DRexc/). In my question the height of the head is not specified. Your answer requires it to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="body">
  <div class="head">
    <div class="head-content">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="growing-area">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.body{
  height:100px; width: 100px;
  display:table;
}
.head {
  height:0px;
  display:table-row;
}
.growing-area {
  position:relative;
  display:table-cell;
}
```

defining a small height of the head is important but the real size is then controlled by the content or you can define the head-content height:

```
.head-content {
  height:30px;
 }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JKQ2y/36/